# Error con simple Hola mundo en Kotlin Intellij IDEA

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, aplicación-movil

Al crear un simple proyecto con Kotlin, y hacer un "Hola mundo" con `println` me da el siguiente error:

> **`Kotlin: Unresolved reference: println`**

Éste es el código que tengo:

```kotlin
fun main() {

    println("Hola Mundo!")

}
```

¿Alguien me podría orientar?

Comment: ¿Cómo creaste el proyecto?

Comment: Tal vez esto te ayude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712046/kotlin-unresolved-reference-in-intellij

Comment: Estas realizando una aplicación móvil, usando Kotlin en IntellijIdea

Answer (score -1):

[println](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/println.html) forma parte del paquete `kotlin.io`. Según la [especificación del lenguaje](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/packages-and-imports.html#importing) se importa implícitamente, al igual que otros paquetes (`kotlin`,
`kotlin.annotation`, `kotlin.collections`, `kotlin.comparisons`, `kotlin.io`, etc).

Hay una pregunta como la tuya en [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31712046) en inglés. La [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34625454) marcada como solución y más votada hasta la fecha dice que la versión del plugin de Kotlin para el IDE y el compilador de tu proyecto deben coincidir.

Por la versión del compilador se refiere a la que aparece en el archivo **build.gradle**. Por ejemplo, en su versión kts se ve así:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.0"
    application
}
```

Puedes averiguar la versión compatible con el plugin yendo a Plugins, buscando Kotlin y tocando la pestaña What's New. En mi caso aparece 1.8.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: yo creo de que esto no tiene nada que ver con la versión de Kotlin. usando el compilador de forma manual podemos añadir la el kotlin-stdlib al classpath y de pronto compilar el código. Yo tengo un proyecto en GitHub en lo cual explico todo esto: https://github.com/jesperancinha/asnsei-the-right-waf/tree/main/demo-projects/closed-world

Comment: @Joao no lo sé. No creo que en [so] sepan menos que nosotros.

Comment: eso es otro tema @Mateo y yo no tengo ninguno interés en discutirlo. Lo que si que digo es que puedes siempre compilar el codigo via la linea de comandos. En la pregunta no se hace ninguna referencia al entorno. Ni siquiera al IntelliJ. Tan poco Eclipse. Por lo tanto mi solución que he testado un mogollón de veces funciona y si yo he testado y funciona en mi maquina, en GitHub actions y en diferentes pipelines entonces lo que digo functiona. Eso es lo que sé y no estoy haciendo ninguna comparación.Y comparaciones de este tipo no son saludables. Pero gracias por tu opinión de todas formas.

Comment: @Joao la pregunta dice IntelliJ Idea. Lo que no menciona si usa Maven o Gradle, aunque como está hablando de Android seguramente esté trabajando con Gradle.

Comment: Ya, eso lo veo ahora, pero en cualquier caso el problema resulta de que el compilador no encuentra la kotlin-stdlib. Y de eso hablo en mi respuesta también.

Comment: @Joao no digo que tu respuesta esté mal. Solo me limité a buscar una respuesta en [so] y me encontré con esa. La traduje y sumé algunos detalles. Tal vez a OP no le sirva pero a otro sí.

Comment: Bueno yo me acuerdo de una cosa y es que hace uns tiempos el IntelliJ no tenía el plugin instalado. Entonces era necesario hacer esta instalación después de la instalación del IntelliJ. E luego por supuesto Intellij ganaba aceso al la librería kotlin-stdlib y el bundle completo. Pero ahora no tienes que hacer nada de eso como ellos mismo dicen aqui: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/get-started-with-kotlin.html.  Entonces si la versión de IntelliJ no es la más reciente, entonces por supuesto de que este error también ocurrirá y en ese caso, tu solición es la indicada @Mateo

Comment: @Joao si no me equivoco siguen utilizando los plugins. Solo que algunos vienen instalados con el IDE y no puedes borrarlos.

Comment: yo también creo que sí @Mateo. IntelliJ está cada vés mejor.